# TFS: Getting test results from remotely executed unit test back into the build agent

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests

I'm trying to make sense of how to use TFS to run unit tests in remote agents using the new configuration files. What I'm looking for:

- Have TFS build the code in a build agent
- The build agent executes unit tests in a remote agent (not the same server as TFS or the build agent)
- Collecting the test results file (*.trx) in the TFS build agent that triggered the test
- Do this in the VS 2012/2013 way

So far I have:

- A test controller and agent properly setup (the controller is **not** associated with TFS)
- A .testsettings file in my repository with execution method set to *Remote Execution* in my test controller
- TFS building and executing the tests remotely using my .testsettings file
- Tests successfully running on the remote agent

Where I'm lost:

- How do I get the .trx file back to my build agent? I see the results successfully published in TFS, but in my build agent's working directory the "tst" directory is empty. If I have the tests running on the build agent I get the trx file here
- By reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28vs.test.runconfig.editor%29) page, I get the idea that starting with VS2012 we should use a .runsettings file instead. However I can't find a lot of documentation on this and can't see how to configure remote execution there

Could someone give some advice here? I feel I'm lost between different ways to get this done.

Thanks

Comment: It not completely clear what you are trying to achieve: if you are using the Default Template test execution, you don't need to do anything special.
If you want to execute tests *after* building, you have to use the LabManagement template (aka Build-Deploy-Test).
If you are executing tests in some other way (e.g. on a *nix machine), then you have to customize the process to import them, which is well documented.

Comment: OK, apologies for the unclear question. I'm successfully executing the tests in a remote test agent. But I can't get the resulting .trx file anywhere. Not on the agent machine and not on the build agent either. Although I see the test results if I open the build in TFS or VS. I'm using the default template where I specify the .testsettings to use and the assembly pattern to match.

Answer (score 0):

TFS is able to import file in TRX format.
An overview of the process is described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/06/publishing-test-results-through-command-line-test-runner.aspx, while the documentation page with the details of MSTest.exe are in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243151.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to go in the right direction, although I'm not sure  how I can take advantage of that: 1) How would I invoke the MSTEST runner to publish the logs? In my .testsettings I can specify a cleanup script that I could use for that, but from there how do I publish the trx file to the **build agent** folder. I can also specify a post test execution script in my build process, but that runs on the build agent, so no trx file there.